# Can't retrieve BadRequest errors when calling .NET CORE 5 Web API microservice from ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-5.0, modelstate

I am trying to retrieve `ModelState` validation errors from a micro service built with .NET Core 5 Web API from a ASP.NET Core MVC frontend.

Say I have a model that looks like this:

```
public class Comment
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

When I call the rest endpoint in the micro service through Swagger to update the `Comment` model without a remark, I get a response body like this:

```
{
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "errors": {
    "Remarks": [
      "The Remarks field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

Awesome! This is what I expect...  However, when I call this endpoint through my MVC project, I can't seem to get the actual "errors".

This is how I am calling the rest endpoint:

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("test");
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(comment), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); 
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync($"api/comments", httpContent);
```

The response object just has a `statusCode` of `BadRequest`. I want to pull the info regarding the errors (the section that says "The Remarks field is required.") but I don't see it in the `Content` or `Headers` property or anything like that.

I am new to micro services and .NET Core - am I doing something wrong?  Do I need to add something to the `startup.cs`? Seems weird that I can get the `BadRequest` status but no supporting problem details.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure your web api controller is not declared with `[ApiController]`.

Web Api Project:

```
//[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CommentsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPut]
    public IActionResult Put([FromBody] Comment model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do your stuff...
            return Ok();
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Mvc Project:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync($"api/comments", httpContent);
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Thanks! This led me to finding the solution. I was adding: response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() after the response returned (forgot to mention in original post) which was wiping out the error details. I check response.IsSuccessStatusCode before determining to return BadResult() or Ok() and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the 'ModelState' as what you did in .NetFramework , you can go with the below approaches,

1. Approach 1

You can validate the ModelState in your end point request, while you adding the below snippet in your program.cs/startup.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
```

This time you will not receive BadRequest (400) , instead you can call your end point and can validate your 'ModelState'.

2. Approach 2

Instead you can get the response as BadRequest when model state invalid and handle the response explicitly in your web/client controller.

3. Approach 3

If you want to handle the custom validation error response , then you can go like FluentValidation or others

Reference: https://medium.com/codex/custom-error-responses-with-asp-net-core-6-web-api-and-fluentvalidation-888a3b16c80f

Courtesy : Medium.com